# project imported to eclipse doesn't show source packages as such

Tags: java, eclipse

Why would be a reason for a project imported to eclipse to not show the package as such and instead just show the regular folder structure?

my .project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>hello-connector</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Maybe you're on the navigator view instead of the package explorer.

Comment: were they imported in the src folder?

Comment: very funny mre, if you want to help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871047/trying-to-follow-your-first-cloud-connector-tutorial

Comment: I am looking at the  package explorer

Comment: yes the .java file is on the src folder

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are not importing an Eclipse project, but rather something IDE independant.

You need to edit the project settings. In the java built path setting, on the first tab, you have to add the source folders as - well - source folders. ;-)

Comment: yes you are right is not an eclipse project per say. Rather I'm dealing with a maven project

Comment: the "Java build path" option is not even there for this specific project!

Comment: Usually I solve this problem by importing the project in a different way (create a new java project with the same name at the same path) then add the src folders. when your project file looks like Chris Gerken's answer, you will find the "Java build path" option.

Answer (score 1):

From the navigator view check the contents of your project's root directory.  You should see a  .classpath file.  If that file is missing then the import didn't work properly (note that two critical project configuration files, .project and .classpath, are sometimes ignored by version control systems and even some file system browsers).  If the .classpath is there you'll have to reconfigure the .classpath manually (or check that you're using the package explorer view).

Try changing your .project to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>hello-connector</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: @david, per your comment above, you should select the project itself and then use Maven -> Update Project Configuration to fix up your java project.

Comment: Yes! but nothing happens, everything stays the same

Comment: can you paste the entire .project file?

Comment: I do not have a .classpath file but upon importing the project multiple times it never got created

Comment: I did and then I went ahead to update the project but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the .project-file I'm assuming this is a Maven-project. Try right-clicking on the project root and select Configure -> Convert to Maven project. After that you may need to right-click the project again and select Maven -> Update project configuration. Hope it helps.

Comment: the option "Configure -> Convert to Maven project" is not present

Comment: Do you have the m2eclipse-plugin installed (I think it or something similar comes pre-installed in newer Eclipses)? Is the Maven-option available under right click-menu? You could try Maven -> Enable dependency management, then do Maven -> Update project configuration. If the option is not available, unfortunately I haven't got another suggestion, at least right now.

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like your pom.xml contains some errors (red box with white x). See if fixing those helps? I don't think I can be of much help to you with this, as the Maven-menu is very different on my own computer (no Maven Nature mentioned anywhere, much more other options).

Answer (score 0):

I got the packages to show by doing the following

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and installing the activation jar after following the instructions of a warning

```
[WARNING] An error occurred during dependency resolution.
    Failed to retrieve javax.activation:activation-1.1-osgi
Caused by: Could not find artifact javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi in mulesoft-releases (http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/)

Try downloading the file manually from:
    https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository/javax.activation/jars/activation-1.1.jar

Then, install it using the command:
    mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.activation -DartifactId=activation -Dversion=1.1-osgi -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
```

Oh I also clear the dependencies on the POM file to just this

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

so after all of that I'm not sure what helped.. I do have other errors but at least I can move on.
Thanks!